# Create Generic Entity model for JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

im trying to modelate with JPA mutiple tables where all of them have the same structure but different names cAfiliado[**PREFIX**].

- cAfiliado**PMX**
- cAfiliado**PMQ**
- cAfiliado**QAW**
- cAfiliado**BMX**

The issue is that there are hundres of tables and maybe more in the future.

So I want to know if its possible to do like one Generic Pojo that can be read from any table specifying the name.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "afiliado"{PREFIX})
    @Data
    public class Afiliado implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "clcuenta")
        private int clAccount;
        
        @Column(name="prefijo")
        private String prefix="";
        
    }
```

Maybe using a parameter or something like that

I have already solved using EntityManager and Native Query

Here is what I have done already

StringBuilder querySearch = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM cafiliado").append(prefix).append(" WHERE Clave = ?1");

SELECT * FROM cafiliado[**PREFIX**]

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, but what you can do is use inheritance to avoid duplication.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
public abstract class Afiliado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "clcuenta")
    private int clAccount;
    
    @Column(name="prefijo")
    private String prefix="";
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "afiliadoPMX")
public class AfiliadoPMX extends Afiliado {}
```